# python error [E053] Could not read config.cfg

Tags: python, nltk, spacy

I have the following error:

````
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to
[nltk_data]     /Users/xz/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package words to /Users/xz/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package words is already up-to-date!
/Users/xz/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/spacy/util.py:738: UserWarning: [W094] Model 'en_core_web_sm' (2.2.5) specifies an under-constrained spaCy version requirement: >=2.2.2. 
This can lead to compatibility problems with older versions, or as new spaCy versions are released, because the model may say it's compatible when it's not. 
Consider changing the "spacy_version" in your meta.json to a version range, with a lower and upper pin. For example: >=3.1.1,<3.2.0
  
OSError: [E053] Could not read config.cfg from /Users/xz/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/config.cfg

```
````

I tried downgrade the spyCy to 2.2.5, but it still does not work.

```
TYPE      NAME             MODEL            VERSION                       
package   en-core-web-sm   en_core_web_sm   2.2.5   --> 2.3.1
```

Comment: Some of those say `/Users/xz`, some say `/Users/xupinz`.  Do you have permission problems here?

Comment: It should be all xz, Thanks

Comment: error shows full path so you could first check if file exists and if it has all privileges to read it. OR maybe you should run it as `root`. What command/code did you use to get this error? You "downgrade" looks like "upgrade" `2.2.5 --> 2.3.1`. How did you try to downgrade it. We can't see your computer, we can't read in your mind - you have to add all details in question (not in comment)

Comment: Agree with furas - what are you actually trying to do? It's not clear what your goal is and therefore we can't say if you should downgrade spaCy or upgrade it or what.